PHP when running a "foreach", find out which item on the list was a match
When this code is run, how can I echo matched variable from $spam_keywords?
Once a variable is matched/found I would like echo it or save it to another veriable.
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$spam_keywords = [
    'spamword1',
    'spamword2',
    'spamword3'
// WILL BE A LOT MORE HERE
];

function checkKeywords($uri, $keywords) {
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
        if (strpos($uri, $keyword) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if (checkKeywords($uri, $spam_keywords)) {
    echo "Here I need to echo which Keyword was matched";
}


A simple way is passing by reference: function checkKeywords($uri, $keywords, &$found_keyword).

On the updated dupe target, see my answer.
